# Removing a sequence of characters from end of string using regex that contain a comma

Tags: c#, regex

I have the following data:

```
I am BOB,FM testing
I am BOB,FM
I am BOB, FM
I am BOB    , FM
I am BOB , FM
BOB, FM I am
I am BOB , FM now
```

I would like to remove the sequence "BOB,FM" from the end of string only.  (With our without spaces in between the commas.)

This would be the correct output:

```
I am BOB,FM testing
I am
I am
I am
I am
BOB, FM I am
I am BOB , FM now
```

This is what I have that is not working so far:

```
mystring = Regex.Replace(mystring, @"[BOB,FM]*$", string.Empty);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can match optional horizontal whitespace chars `[\p{Zs}\t]*` before and after `BOB` and the comma in between FM whihout listing the characters in a character class.

To match whitespace chars, you could use `\s*`

```
[\p{Zs}\t]*\bBOB[\p{Zs}\t]*,[\p{Zs}\t]*FM$
```

In the replacement use an empty string.

[Regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5b%5cp%7bZs%7d%5ct%5d*%5cbBOB%5b%5cp%7bZs%7d%5ct%5d*%2c%5b%5cp%7bZs%7d%5ct%5d*FM%5cr%3f%24&i=I+am+BOB%2cFM+testing%0d%0aI+am+BOB%2cFM%0d%0aI+am+BOB%2c+FM%0d%0aI+am+BOB++++%2c+FM%0d%0aI+am+BOB+%2c+FM%0d%0aBOB%2c+FM+I+am%0d%0aI+am+BOB+%2c+FM+now&o=m)

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
var result = Regex.Replace(text, @"[\s-[\n]]*BOB[\s-[\n]]*,[\s-[\n]]*FM[\s-[\n]]*$", "", RegexOptions.Multiline);
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5B%5Cs-%5B%5Cn%5D%5D*BOB%5B%5Cs-%5B%5Cn%5D%5D*%2C%5B%5Cs-%5B%5Cn%5D%5D*FM%5B%5Cs-%5B%5Cn%5D%5D*%24&i=I%20am%20BOB%2CFM%20testing%0D%0AI%20am%20BOB%2CFM%0D%0AI%20am%20BOB%2C%20FM%0D%0AI%20am%20BOB%20%20%20%20%2C%20FM%0D%0AI%20am%20BOB%20%2C%20FM%0D%0ABOB%2C%20FM%20I%20am%0D%0AI%20am%20BOB%20%2C%20FM%20now&r=&o=m).

Other possible patterns look like

```cs
@"[^\S\r\n]*BOB[^\S\r\n]*,[^\S\r\n]*FM[^\S\n]*$"
@"[\p{Zs}\t]*BOB[\p{Zs}\t]*,[\p{Zs}\t]*FM[\p{Zs}\t\r]*$"
```

*Details*:

- `[\s-[\n]]*` - zero or more whitespace chars other than LF
- `BOB` - a `BOB` text
- `[\s-[\n]]*,[\s-[\n]]*`  - a `,` enclosed with optional zero or more whitespace chars other than LF
- `FM` - a `FM` string
- `[\s-[\n]]*` - zero or more whitespace chars other than LF
- `$` - end of a line.